# file upload does not retain values

Tags: grails, file-upload

I'm working on Grails Filters and I need to save the contents of the uploaded file in the `after{}` of the filter. I see that the "data" of the uploaded file is getting lost here. Can you please suggest a way to retain this data?

Comment: Why are you dealing with file uploads in a filter?

Comment: Data had to be passed from one system to another, so these values are stored in a particular folder

Comment: What do you mean the "data" is getting lost?